# MEFContrib.MVC3: Exporting Controllers with Base Classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, export, mef

I have opened up a question [on CodePlex](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/discussions/271228) but have not received any responses at all.

Basically, I have a base controller that all of my controllers inherit from.  When I create a new MVC3 project, put my controllers in another assembly, and add MEFContrib.MVC3 to the project, everything works great.  When I make any of the controllers inherit from my base class, they can no longer be found.

I am not familiar enough with MEFContrib to know what exactly is breaking, but I have tried to decorate my controllers with `ExportAttribute`s and that has not worked, either.

All of this is a different assembly than the main MVC project:

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    ...
}

//  This controller cannot be found.
public class HomeController : MyBaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index ()
    {
        // Do Stuff
        return View ();
    }
}

// This controller can be found.
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // yada, yada, yada...
}
```

**Edit:**

counsellorben was exactly right.  I had dependencies that were not properly marked for export and so the controllers could not be properly composed.  I stepped through each of my dependencies, stepping through their own dependencies, and found the few I missed.

Comment: Please specify any dependencies which are imported into your MyController class.  The most likely issue is that there is a problem with a dependency in the MyController class, and this causes the same problem with any controller inheriting from MyController.

Comment: @counsellorben - going to take a look and see if that is what it is.

Comment: @counsellorben - I was able to create a sample project with a base class and dependencies and it worked just fine.  If you create an answer I'll accept it since that seems to be my problem.  Was trying to port an application from Ninject to MEFContrib's IoC.  Seems like it's going to be a bit of work to figure out dependencies.  As an aside, is there a way to see which depenedencies are causing MEF to not be able to compose the proper parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue is that there is a problem with a dependency in your `MyController` class.  This will cause a problem with any controller inheriting from MyController.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144683/handle-reflectiontypeloadexception-during-mef-composition) for some sample code you can use to try and diagnose where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to decorate with the `InheritedExport` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, Nate. It was actually because I missed a dependency--just a silly mistake.